# logback.xml in classpath getting executed along with logging.config Environment argument spring boot

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project(version 1.3.6) and i have added logback.xml to the project. On creating an executable jar, the logback.xml is getting included in the jar and also working as expected. As the development is done on a windows system, so **logback.xml in classpath** adds the logs to file at path **F:/application/logs/abc.log.**

But on deployment of the jar on unix server, i want to provide logback.xml configuration from external file with a different path for logging file say **(/opt/logs/abc.log)**. I used -Dlogging.config argument while executing my jar file to provide the external logback.xml configuration file as below.

```
java -Dlogging.config=/path/to/logback.xml -jar ABC.jar
```

On running the above command, the logs are getting created successfully at **/opt/logs/abc.log** as per the external file configuration but the issue is that **F:/application/logs/abc.log** directory structure also gets created with a 0 byte file though no logging is being done in this.

So if i am running my application from say /local directory on the server, then the below directories are getting created.

```
/local/F:/application/logs/abc.log
```

My question is how can we avoid the classpath log file directory structure(**/local/F:/application/logs/abc.log**) from getting created if external logback.xml configuration is used.

My logback.xml is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">
<appender name="ROLLINGFILE"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>F:/FRF/logs/iqcx-ticketing.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>F:/FRF/logs/iqcx-ticketing-%d{yyyy-MM}.%i.zip
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{ISO8601} [%thread] - %-5level %logger %X - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root>
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLINGFILE" />
</root>
<logger name="iqcxLogger" level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLINGFILE" />
</logger>
<logger name="org.springframework" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLINGFILE" />
</logger>
<logger name="org.mybatis.spring" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLINGFILE" />
</logger>
<logger name="org.hibernate.validator" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLINGFILE" />
</logger>
<logger name="org.apache.commons.beanutils" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLINGFILE" />
</logger>

</configuration>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723324/dlogback-configurationfile-logback-xml-ignored-when-running-spring-boot/

Comment: Thanks for this link, but it seems to be something different from my issue as i am already running my application with -Dlogging.config added but both classpath and external logging files are getting created as per my question description. Though logging is happening correctly as per external config file only.

Comment: @ltalhouarne : Any specific reason for downvote as the link you have posted is not my question and also i am using the config as suggested in your link.

Comment: my apologies, read too fast. Will upvote when allowed again

Comment: @Raghav plz upvote if it solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since logback.xml is in classpath F:/application/logs/abc.log will be created unless you override `logging.file` property by adding `-Dlogging.file=/opt/logs/abc.log` argument to command line