# Throttling JDBCTemplate Logs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback, jdbctemplate

I am using Spring JDBCTemplate for executing SQL queries. When the log level `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` is set to `DEBUG`, the SQL statement is logged each time the query is fired.

The problem is that I have some queries that get fired hundreds of times. So the application logs are filled with repetitive logs of the same query and all other log statements get completely drowned out making the log incredibly hard to understand.

Is there some way to "throttle" these repetitive statements so that they are not printed as often?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom `logback.xml` and point spring boot to it. See the [discussion in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723324/dlogback-configurationfile-logback-xml-ignored-when-running-spring-boot) on how to do that.
2. Add a [DuplicateMessageFilter](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) to your logback.xml
3. Any identical messages should be removed from your logs.