# Configure spring boot application using command line argument

Tags: java, spring-boot

So far I have found 2 methods to configure spring boot application at startup, one uses `-D` and the other one uses `--` like this:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test app.jar
java -jar --spring.profiles.active=test app.jar
```

Sometimes, the first works, sometimes the second works. As a developer found, when `run` method in the following example is not given `args` parameter, `--` method does not work, but `-D` does.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

While today, I was configuring logback at command line, and found that `-Dlogback.configurationFile=/full_path/logback.xml` does not work but `--logging.config=file:logback.xml`does.

Above may have other reason, maybe `logback.configurationFile` is wrong, but it acts like `-D` and `--` difference.

Then my question is what is `-D` and `--`, is it Java or Spring thing? why it varies between not working and working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-D` standard java option sets a system property value as a couple *property, value* while by default `SpringApplication` converts any command line option argument (substantially `String` values corresponding to `String[] args`with the prefix `--`, e.g. `--spring.profiles.active=test`) to a property and adds it to the Spring environment eventually overriding the property with the same name if it exists.

I'm seeing a possible cause of not predictable behaviour in the wrong position of the command line option like the line `java -jar --spring.profiles.active=test app.jar` you included because all command line options should stand after the jar so the command should be rewritten as  `java -jar app.jar --spring.profiles.active=test` to ensure the correct conversion into property by the Spring framework. Be aware that in the case your Spring application tries to read a value from the system while you are passing the property as a command line option argument the application will not work, same will happen when you sets the system property and the Spring application tries to read it as a command line property.

For the logback problem the `--logging.config=file:logback.xml` command line options argument is working because is it equal to override the value of the `logging.config` common application property present in the Spring framework, the other `logback.configurationFile` option is not a Spring common property so it is not automatically handled by the framework.

Answer (score 2):

To explain this answer, simply open Command prompt or terminal window & type

```
$ java --help
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
  ...
 Arguments following the main class, source file, -jar <jarfile>,
 -m or --module <module>/<mainclass> are passed as the arguments to
 main class.

 where options include:
    ...
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    ...
```

Based on this help doc, `-D` & `--` is from java :

- `-D` is an option used to set system property(can be called as VM arguments)  & `--` is an argument[s] that is passed to main class; can be called as program arguments.
- That is reason when your `run` is not given `args` parameter, `--` is not working but `-D` does .
- Regarding `logback` issue, VM argument won't work because its not managed by [spring framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging) but passing `logging.config` as program argument does; [SO reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723324/dlogback-configurationfile-logback-xml-ignored-when-running-spring-boot).