# Externalise CONFIGs and LOGBACK outside of the Code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I have Spring Boot App in Gradle with Liquibase changesets.

This code is **multi module app** with about **four modules in hexagonal architecture**.

[image]

and the resources folder structure looks like this for **doctors-data-deploy module**:

[image]

My Issue is I want to put **configs** and **logback** files outside of the code, how can I externalise these files from code.

**I want to run the code in 2 ways, as follows:**

1. And I want to run my code as Jar file and want to pass these configs and logback files while running the jar
   e.g. **java -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar doctors-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dlogback-config-file=logback-spring.xml -Dother-config-file=application.yml**

   **Not Sure what will be the exact syntax for this?**
2. If I externalise both the config and logback files, how could I pass these property in my coode If I run the spring boot app as it is by clicking on the run button in intelliJ.

Below is my **application yml** file

```
server:
  tomcat:
    connectionTimeout: 300000
management:
  endpoint:
    mappings:
      enabled: true
spring:
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    hikari:
      minimum-idle: 5
      maximumPoolSize: 20
      idleTimeout: 30000
      maxLifetime: 2000000
      connectionTimeout: 30000
      poolName: data-pool
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      use-new-id-generator-mappings: false
      ddl-auto: none
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          scheduler:
            instanceId: AUTO
          jobStore:
            class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
            useProperties: false
            misfireThreshold: 60000
            clusterCheckinInterval: 5000
            isClustered: true
          threadPool:
            class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
            threadCount: 10
            threadPriority: 5
            threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true
```

Below is my **logback-spring.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<configuration>

    <springProperty scope="context" name="app_name" source="spring.application.name"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="environment" source="param_env" defaultValue="default_env"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="tenant" source="param_tenant" defaultValue="default_tenant"/>

    <property name="GENERIC_PATTERN"
              value="[%date{ISO8601}] [%p] [%t] [%X{traceId:-}] [%X{orderId:-}] [%X{batchJobId:-}] [%X{username:-}] [%X{functional-context}] [%c{2}] %4L | %m%n"/>
    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="$GENERIC_PATTERN"/>
    <property name="CHARSET" value="UTF-8"/>

    <property name="LOG_DIR"
              value="logs/${envname:-${environment}}/${param_dtlogname:-${app_name}}"/>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.dt" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="com.dt" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor"
            level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO"/>

    <!-- Auto configuration report-->
    <logger name="org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener"
            level="TRACE"/>

    <springProfile name="local,component-test,component-test-security,scheduler-test">

        <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder>
                <charset>${CHARSET}</charset>
                <pattern>${GENERIC_PATTERN}</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <logger name="zuul.web.request.logger" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </root>

    </springProfile>


        <appender name="FILE_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

            <file>${LOG_DIR}/${param_dtlogname}-${HOSTNAME}.log</file>

            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- daily rollover -->
                <fileNamePattern>
                    ${LOG_DIR}/${param_dtlogname}-${HOSTNAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                </fileNamePattern>
                <maxFileSize>1GB</maxFileSize>
                <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
                <!-- keep 30 days worth of history -->
                <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>

            <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
                <providers>
                    <mdc/>
                    <pattern>
                        <omitEmptyFields>true</omitEmptyFields>
                        <pattern>
                            {
                            "app_name": "${app_name}",
                            "HOSTNAME":"${HOSTNAME}",
                            "environment":"${environment}"
                            }
                        </pattern>
                    </pattern>
                    <logLevel/>
                    <timestamp/>
                    <threadName/>
                    <logstashMarkers/>
                    <tags/>
                    <arguments/>
                    <version/>
                    <stackTrace/>
                    <loggerName/>
                    <threadName/>
                    <message/>
                </providers>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder>
                <charset>${CHARSET}</charset>
                <pattern>${GENERIC_PATTERN}</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <appender name="CONSOLE_JSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
                <fieldNames>
                    <timestamp>timestamp</timestamp>
                    <message>logdata</message>
                    <version>[ignore]</version>
                    <levelValue>[ignore]</levelValue>
                </fieldNames>
                <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <appender name="API_FILE_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

            <file>${LOG_DIR}/api-${param_dtlogname}-${HOSTNAME}.log</file>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- daily rollover -->
                <fileNamePattern>
                    ${LOG_DIR}/api-${param_dtlogname}-${HOSTNAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                </fileNamePattern>
                <maxFileSize>1GB</maxFileSize>
                <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
                <!-- keep 30 days worth of history -->
                <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>

            <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
                <fieldNames>
                    <timestamp>[ignore]</timestamp>
                    <message>logdata</message>
                    <version>[ignore]</version>
                    <levelValue>[ignore]</levelValue>
                </fieldNames>
                <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <appender name="APPLICATION_FILE_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

            <file>${LOG_DIR}/startup-${param_dtlogname}-${HOSTNAME}.log</file>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- daily rollover -->
                <fileNamePattern>
                    ${LOG_DIR}/startup-${param_dtlogname}-${HOSTNAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                </fileNamePattern>
                <maxFileSize>1GB</maxFileSize>
                <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
                <!-- keep 30 days worth of history -->
                <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>

            <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
                <fieldNames>
                    <timestamp>timestamp</timestamp>
                    <message>logdata</message>
                    <version>[ignore]</version>
                    <levelValue>[ignore]</levelValue>
                </fieldNames>
                <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <logger name="api.logger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="API_FILE_APPENDER"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="application.startup.logger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="APPLICATION_FILE_APPENDER"/>
        </logger>

        <appender name="SENTRY" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                <level>ERROR</level>
            </filter>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>${GENERIC_PATTERN}</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
            <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER"/>
            <appender-ref ref="SENTRY"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

Can someone please help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to externalize SpringBoot configuration, the correct environment property to set is

`--spring.config.location`.

Please refer to the relevant documentation page for further info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html.

As for logback, you may want to try the solutions proposed here [-Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml ignored when running Spring-Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723324/dlogback-configurationfile-logback-xml-ignored-when-running-spring-boot).

In order to pass program arguments in IntelliJ, simply go to run/debug configurations, select the desired run configuration, and place all the arguments in the 'Program Arguments' text field.